# How to Restore data from MS SQL 2012 to MS SQL 2008 using .bak file. Is this Possible?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement that am facing difficulty i.e. restoring a data from MS SQL 2012 to MS SQL 2008 using .bak file. when am trying to restore , am getting an error. is this possibility to restore this to downgrade.

can any one help me how to restore ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQL Server will not go backwards. The only way you can do this is Using SSIS to transfer the data or you can use the import/export utility.

On your 2012 Server Right click on the DB you want to export data from and scroll down to tasks and then choose export data it will have you then insert all of the information for both the source and destination servers then on the summary page click mappings and make sure they are correct for what you need and the DB it is going to is correct. Then follow the screens until you can click finish. YOu may have too play with it for a little bit to get it to behave nicely but this should work for you.

If all you have is a BAK file you may have to resotre it to a dummy DB on the 2012 server first.

Comment: You can also use a data scripting tool. It can end up being a very, very large script, but in a pinch it can do the job.

Comment: True that can work too. I just prsonally like to see the progress. As it goes through the process.

Comment: Agree, SSIS is probably a lot cleaner. Sometimes alternate tools or methods are nice to have as options, though! I've seen SSIS data export wizards fail repeatedly. What do you do, then?

Comment: Yeah I have too. They are really finicky I have messed with it enough to usually know why it is failing. I have had a few cases where it wouldn't work and I just went to creating a project in SSIS to do it. I haven't delt with any third party software. I work for a bank so anything that is not completely necessary isn't needed.